# OLEDB Source view in SSIS not refreshing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have created a view in a database,DbConfig.The view definition is

```
use DbConfig
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_ETL_priority]
AS
SELECT
'EF5F126FU1'    code
,'N'                activeind
,'Unknown'      decode
,   0               prioritydays
UNION ALL
SELECT  distinct
cast(LTRIM(RTRIM([priority_code])) as varchar(10))
,case when [inactive] =0 then 'Y' else 'N' end
,cast(LTRIM(RTRIM([description])) as varchar(30))
,[days]
FROM OPEN_DB.[dbo].[rm_priority]
```

now the view is using as OLEDB source for one of the data flows.It works fine.

There are databases called  OPEN_DB_UK,OPEN_DB_KD,OPEN_DB_Usa, all got same structure as that of OPEN_DB and containe same table rm_priority
Now if i renamed OPEN_DB  to OPEN_DB_old and  OPEN_DB_UK to OPEN_DB then view would have to give data rows form the new database(uk database) right?
yes it does give when query the view select * from [V_VAT] in SSMS .But in SSIS OLEDB source it still gives the data rows based on the first database OPEN_DB.
Why it is not giving data rows based on new database that is OPEN_DB_uk in SSIS OLEDB source

Have any body faced similar problem?Is it due to distinct in the view definition?

Any SSIS expert please help

Answer (score 0):

Some time back I have faced the similar kind of issue and the issue got resolved by re-creating the connecitons again. Delete the existing connection and create a new connection and configure the same. Please try this approch and let me know your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But there are several views .All are refreshing.The problem is only with this view.If i drop and recreate it it will work